# Toastr JS Notification on show/close events

Tags: javascript, events, listener, toastr

I'm using Toastr Notifications and I'm trying to do something when the notification appears and when it disappears or is manually closed. I'm not really sure how to do this...I've seen the developer briefly explain it here: https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr/issues/88

But I'm new to JS and didn't exactly understand what to do. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
toastr.options = {
        "closeButton": true,
        "debug": false,
        "newestOnTop": false,
        "progressBar": true,
        "positionClass": "toast-top-full-width",
        "preventDuplicates": false,
        "showDuration": "1000",
        "hideDuration": "1000",
        "timeOut": "0",
        "extendedTimeOut": "0",
        "showEasing": "swing",
        "hideEasing": "linear",
        "showMethod": "slideDown",
        "hideMethod": "slideUp"
      }

      toastr.success("New Order");
      var playAudio = true;
      var audio = new Audio('notificationSound.mp3');
      while (playAudio) {
        audio.play();
      }
```

I want the audio to start when the notification appears and keep looping until its closed.

Comment: Can you provide sample code of what you're doing?

Comment: For sure! I edited my question

Answer (score 1):

`toastr.subscribe();` is triggered each time any of those mentioned events happened. If you want to log something to console every time that happens, use

```
toastr.subscribe(() = > {
     console.log("logged something");
});
```

Want to access information about that event?

```
toastr.subscribe((...args) = > {
     console.log(args);
});
```

The `args` variable holds the information about the event.

Comment: What would the args variable be if I wanted to do something when a toastr appears and is closed

Comment: Apparently this object is passed down as the argument https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr/blob/50092cc604850a16c985520b63df184d3e0b4086/toastr.js#L228 . Check your console, I assume there will be a toastId number representing each event type.

Comment: What is "this object"? Also what exactly do I have to type in to get real, working code. Can you provide an example?